# Facelet : <ui:insert> cannot be put inside attribute value problem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Im currently experimenting with facelets in JSF 2.0.

I currently have a case where a common grid definition is used by 2 facelets,
differs only in some areas like the bean name, the list name, the title, the grid id.

So what i have in mind is :

1. create template for that grid, making use of `<ui:insert>` in the areas that can differ between pages that use it
2. those 2 pages, make use of the template, supplying the parameters for the template with `<ui:define>`

Here is my gridTemplate.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:head>
    <title>#{msgs.title}</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template/masterlayout.xhtml">
        <p:dataTable id="<ui:insert name='gridId' />" var="rpb"
            value="#{<ui:insert name='bean' />.<ui:insert name='list' />}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h3><ui:insert name='title' /></h3>
            </f:facet>

            .....

            <f:facet name="footer">
                #{fn:length(<ui:insert name='bean' />.<ui:insert name='list' />)} records<br />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here's one of the facelet that makes use of the grid template :

```
<ui:composition template="gridTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="gridId">grid</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="bean">myBean</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="list">myList</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="title">my message !</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And this experiment ends up with :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /gridTemplate.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 17] The value of attribute "id" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)

root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /gridTemplate.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 17] The value of attribute "id" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:394)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:368)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:297)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:92)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:162)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:161)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:83)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:79)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
```

I assume that this approach is not plausible, hence there should be a better solution for this kind of needs.

Should i use JSF Facelet Tag or JSF Composite Tag for this kind of case ?

Please share your opinions .. Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make a composite component instead of template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="list"/>
    <cc:attribute name="title"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable id="#{cc.id}" var="rpb"
            value="#{cc.attrs.list}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h3>#{cc.attrs.title}</h3>
            </f:facet>

            .....

            <f:facet name="footer">
                #{fn:length(cc.attrs.list)} records<br />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>

</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

This component has to be placed in a folder inside the `resources` folder, on the root of your webapp. The name of the component will be the same as the filename. So for this example lets call the component `myComponent` inside the `/resources/components` folder:

```
/resources/components/myComponent.xhtml
```

Then in any page you want to include the component you just have to do include the namespace of your component

```
xmlns:albert="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
```

and render your component:

```
<albert:myComponent id="..." title="..." list=#{someBean.someList} />
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing your thought on making use of the composite component to solve the problem. But i have this doubt whether it's a bit much to make a composite component for a grid to be shared on just 2 jsf pages ?

Comment: this answer is straight to the point and more accurate than several "tutorials" on the web on this subject. Congratulations